# Get elements with certain condition from List(Of)

Tags: vb.net, list, class, extension-methods

I'm iterating through a List(Of MyClass) in order to find elements with certain conditions.

For example, in one case, I need to find all of these elements and do something with them:

```
    For Each nCell As clsCell In colCell
        If nCell.TempClickIndex = nCell.ClickIndex Then
            If nCell.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE Then
```

I would like to know if there's any way to simplify this.

I'm dreaming of something like this:

```
For Each nCell As clsCell in colCell.GetSkypeCells()
```

The call "GetSkypeCells" would do just what I do above and would handle the selection internally.

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

This is my colCell:

```
Public colCell As New clsCellListExtender.List(Of clsCell)

Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class clsCellListExtender

Public Class List(Of T)
    Inherits Collection(Of T)

    Private _iID As Integer = 0
    Private i As Integer = 0

    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
        'your checks here
        'i += 1
        'If i > 20000 Then
        '    i = 0
        'End If
        Debug.Assert(g_bCheck = False)

        If TypeOf (item) Is clsCell Then
            _iID += 1
            Dim nCell As clsCell = TryCast(item, clsCell)
            nCell.TempID = _iID
        End If

        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End Sub

End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
For Each nCell as clsCell In colCell.Where(Function(x) x.TempClickIndex = x.ClickIndex AndAlso x.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE)
    'Do stuff with nCell
Next
```

For your "dream" solution, you could add an extension method to whatever type `colCell` is that returns the result of the above LINQ.

Getting this to work with the nested class, and the generic type was a little tricky, but I finally got it.

```
Public Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function GetSkypeCells(Of T As clsCell)(colCell As clsCellListExtender.List(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Return colCell.Where(Function(x) x.TempClickIndex = x.ClickIndex AndAlso x.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE)
    End Function
End Module
```

---

Here is a small console application with a working extension method.  I left the implementation blank to save space, but you should be able to fill it in from what is above.  Just let me know if you have any issues.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a As New clsCellListExtender.List(Of clsCell)
        For Each cell As clsCell In a.GetSkypeCells()
            'Do things with cell here
        Next
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class clsCellListExtender
    Public Class List(Of T)
        Inherits Collection(Of T)
        Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
            '...
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class

Public Class clsCell
    '...
End Class

Module Extensions
    <Extension>
    Public Function GetSkypeCells(Of T As clsCell)(colCell As clsCellListExtender.List(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Return colCell.Where(Function(x) x.TempClickIndex = x.ClickIndex AndAlso x.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I've edited my post because the following isn't working for me: For Each nCell As clsCell In colCell.GetSkypeCells Could you tell me where I went wrong? The compiler tells me "GetSkypeCells is not a member of clsCellListExnteder.List(Of clsCell)". I used your extension example like this:     Public Function GetSkypeCells(colCell As clsCellListExtender.List(Of clsCell)) As IEnumerable(Of clsCell)
        Return colCell.Where(Function(x) x.TempClickIndex = x.ClickIndex AndAlso x.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE)
    End Function

Comment: If you really have your own implementation of `List` as a nested class within `clsCellListExtender`, the extension method declaration should look like this `Public Function GetSkypeCells(colCell As clsCellListExtender.List(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of clsCell)`. *I think*, the naming is really messing with my head.

Comment: I may have to throw this in to an actual VB project to get everything right with the nested class and generics. I'll have something for you in a few minutes.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I tried everything I could imagine but somehow I didn't manage to get it right.

Comment: Sorry, I had some surprise meetings I had to attend, Looking at it now.

Comment: This doesn't work yet. The error I'm getting is "ClickIndex is not a member of T, TempClickIndex is not a member of T, StandardCellType is not a member of T).

Comment: Ahh, you are absolutely right, I missed a constraint on `T`. I must have dropped it as I was editing and moving stuff around.  The extension method should look like `Public Function GetSkypeCells(Of T As clsCell)(colCell As clsCellListExtender.List(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)`.  The generic type needs to be constrained to `clsCells` so that it can access its members.  Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For Each nCell As clsCell In colCell.FindAll(Function(c) c.TempClickIndex = c.ClickIndex And
                                                         c.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE)

Next
```

You can adapt this and create an extension-method, then you can call it with `colCell.GetSkypeCells()`

```
<Extension>
Public Function GetSkypeCells(c As List(Of clsCell)) As List(Of clsCell)
    Return c.FindAll(Function(cc As clsCell) cc.TempClickIndex = cc.ClickIndex And
                                             cc.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAGE)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's extension method `Where`

```
Dim skypeCalls = 
    colCell.Where(Function(cell) cell.TempClickIndex = cell.ClickIndex).
           .Where(Function(cell) cell.StandardCellType = eStandardCellType.SCT_SKYPEMESSAG)

For Each skypeCall in skypeCalls
    ' Do something
Next
```